# Finding area under curve $y=e^{-x} $ and my attempt

Tags: calculus

I need to find area limit as t goes to infiniy of A (t) under curve $y=e^{-x}$ , $x$ axis and straight lines $ x=t
$and $x=-t $

I have graphed here [image]

I have set up double integral to calculate area as

[image]

But as t goes to infinity area is going to infinity , but in textbook answer is 2 .What am inissing? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the curve $e^{-|t|}$? Because that's what your graph shows. If so, your integral will need to be split into two parts (from $-t$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $t$), in which the integrand can be rewritten to remove the absolute value signs.

Comment: Your graph is symmetric around $x=0$, so do you mean $e^{-|x|}$? If so, that is also missing from your calculations.

Comment: @JohnHughes maybe yesyou areright , textbook stated $e^{-x}$

Comment: @Henrik doesn't double integral take care of that

Comment: The function is even , break it in two parts from $0$ to $\infty$. Evaluate any one part and multiply it by 2.

Comment: but this curve is not $e^{-x}$

Comment: @godonichia: I was trying to make the exact same point as John. And it's far from clear to me what you're trying to achieve by that double integral, but it surely doesn't account for the symmetry.

Comment: @Henrik then what is the area ihave calculated

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x}dx$ is $\infty$, so as such your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-t}^te^{-|x|}dx=\int_{-t}^0e^{+x}dx+\int_0^te^{-x}dx=e^t\Big|_{-t}^0-e^{-t}\Big|_0^{t}=2-2e^{-t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a easy trick. By looking at your graph, I am assuming that function is, $y=e^{-|x|}$.

Required area = $\lim_{t\to \infty}$ $2*\large\int_{0}^{t}{e^{-x}.dx}$ = $2$

For double integral setup,

$I=\int_{-t}^{t}\int_{0}^{y} dy.dx$  , where $y =e^{-|x|}$

Which gives, $I=\int_{-t}^{t}e^{-|x|}.dx$ , you still have to divide this into two part as,
$I=2\int_{0}^{t}e^{-x}.dx$

Comment: I have done this using single variable calculus , thanksanywways

Comment: Does this solve the query?